# Could there be a situation like bringing only the data of the 1st column to first row and the 2nd row the data of the 2nd column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 5 columns (column a, column b, column c, column d, column e)

Could there be a situation like bringing only the data of the 1st column to first row and the 2nd row the data of the 2nd column?

How can i do this situation ?

Edit v2:

Sorry i couldn't explain correctly. Sometimes c column can repeat. There is a column (column e) i want to group my result, that column's data like 1-2-3-4 like:

1. abc  --  --  --   1
2. --  abc  --  --   1
3. --  --  abc  --   1
4. --  --  abc  --   1
5. --  --   --   abc 1
6. abc  --  --  --   2
7. --  abc  --  --   2
8. --  --  abc  --   2
9. --  --   --   abc 2

Btw I have over 500 rows and when group value changes, abc starts at column a.

Answer (score 0):

Strange request, but `APPLY` does this pretty simply:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (t.a, null, null, null, null),
             (null, t.b, null, null, null),
             (null, null, t.c, null, null),
             (null, null, null, t.d, null),
             (null, null, null, null, t.e)
     ) v(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as 
 (
     select t.*, row_number()over(order by(select 1))rn from mytable t
 ) 
 select (case when rn=1 then column_a end) column_a,
             (case when rn=2 then column_b end) column_b,
             (case when rn=3 then column_c end) column_c,
             (case when rn=4 then column_d end) column_d,
             (case when rn=5 then column_e end) column_e
 from cte;
```

If you want the rows in any specific order then instead of order by(select 1) you can use your prefered order by clause